# Springframework webflow variable class name not found

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have problem with initialization of spring webflow variables. 
I have two flows xml's and they looks same, but when opens one of them spring throws this exception. In flows are two kind of variables initialization:

```
<var name="bean" bean="beanName" scope="flow"  />
```

and

```
<set attribute="id" value="${'someId'}" scope="flow" />
```

Here is exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:222)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.toClass(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:958)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.parseFlowVariable(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:389)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.buildVariables(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:172)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowAssembler.directAssembly(FlowAssembler.java:103)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowAssembler.assembleFlow(FlowAssembler.java:91)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.assembleFlow(DefaultFlowHolder.java:109)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.getFlowDefinition(DefaultFlowHolder.java:84)
at org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinition(FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java:61)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:138)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
at com.exigen.base.ui.flow.DefaultFlowController.handleRequest(DefaultFlowController.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
... 82 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but if you want to use `<var>` element you **NEED** both name and class attributes.
like
    `<var name="myVar" class="com.example.var.MyVar"/>`

plus, you don't need to define beans in wefblow, you can automatically use the ones defined in your applicationContext

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue. Problem was in webflow schemes versions mismatch. One of my flow xml using 1.0, while system using 2.0.